# file Upload Verifier - jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hiee,
I want to design a frontend of an Uploader page so that
**only JPG file can be selected**
**Max file size should be 1mb**

I want to do this check in JavaScript [not in PHP or so ...], can anyone help me ?

*[I've no code to show]*

Comment: You'll have to check on your server too, because you can't prevent somebody from simply POSTing to your URL.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112575/client-checking-file-size-using-html5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript solution i found.
If you want jquery only. convert it to jquery :-)

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function getSize()
{
    var myFSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var filepath = document.upload.file.value;
    var thefile = myFSO.getFile(filepath);
    var size = thefile.size;
    alert(size + " bytes");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="upload">
<input type="file" name="file">
<input type="button" value="Size?" onClick="getSize();">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's unfriendly to users to insist firmly that filenames must indicate file type, but if you disagree with me you can check the filename on your `<input>` element. Checking actual file content and size is harder, and will require either Flash or new HTML5 features.

(The file name, stripped of any other path information and possibly even disguised with bogus path information, is available as the `<input>` element's "value" attribute.)

Answer (score 1):

You may check the extensions (which does not check mime type!)

with something like this:

```
var el = document.getElementById('filename');
var fileName = el.value;
//do some regex magic to validate for /jpg\z/i
```

Also: You will also HAVE to check on the server. There's nothing stopping anyone with javascript disabled to upload .exe or other creepy large files.

For the rest I don't think there are many currently backwards compatible solutions for javascript. If you really want to do it client side, you might want to look into flash - since it has more permissions to check it. (Still you need to validate on the server side)

Another solution might be the html5 file api:
http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-file

examples with firefox >3.6:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_files_from_web_applications
(Still you need to validate on the server)

Answer (score 1):

i think u can use pluploader for your page.that can be handle your requirement very well.this is the link.http://www.plupload.com/example_queuewidget.php

Comment: This also relies on flash, silverlight or html5

Comment: @Arend it doesnot rely on flash, silverlight or html5. it will auto detect whats available or fallback to HTML4