# Calculate File Size using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I need to calculate file size using javascript before the file starts to upload in server size. I need do the file size operation in client size itself.

Pls help me guys.,

Thanks..

Comment: You can do this in newer browsers with the HTML5 file APIs, but not in older browsers unless you use Flash or something.

Comment: @EvilP: i have tried a code which had been posted in a site.
http://www.kavoir.com/2009/01/check-for-file-size-with-javascript-before-uploading.html. it is working in IE but it is asking for ActiveX Control. It is not supported in Chrome and Safari...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112575/client-checking-file-size-using-html5

Answer (score 3):

New APIs in HTML5 will allow you to interact with files - so you need the users to be on latest browsers for this to work:

[jquery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/)

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 will helpful for you.
check the [similar question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112575/client-checking-file-size-using-html5)

[check this also](http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-file-drag-drop-read-analyze-upload-progress-bars/)