# Get image size (in bytes) before uploading

Tags: javascript, html

Javascript can get file size (size in bytes)?

I need before uploading image, understand what is image size, its possible ?

Comment: Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112575/client-checking-file-size-using-html5

Answer (score 1):

Get a handle to the `<input type="file">` element, then:

```
var file = fileinput.files && fileinput.files[0];
if( file ) {
     console.log( file.size, file.type );
}
else if( !("files" in fileInput)) {
    // not supported
}
else {
    //No file selected
}
```