# File size detect before upload issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following is my code in which I am detecting filesize before upload but this `document.getElementById('file').files[0]` property is not supported by some browsers. All I wanna do is if on detecting browser doesnot support this property user gets alert of `no` else `yes`. Kindly let me know how to do this?

```
var filename = document.getElementById('file').files[0];
if (typeof filename === 'undefined' || filename === false)
{
alert('no');
}
     else if(filename && filename.size < 10240) { // 10485760 = 10 MB (this size is in bytes)
     alert('yes');
     $('#processing-modal').modal('show');
     return false;
     }
```

Comment: You can find more information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497404/get-file-size-before-uploading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got it almost. Check for the property beforehand:

```
var element = document.getElementById('file');
if (typeof element.files !== "undefined") {
    // and now your code
}
```

[edit] Or as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4307882/838733):

```
if (typeof FileReader !== "undefined") {
    // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, IE does not support the HTML5 file API (big surprise right?)

we can simply check the files property of the input - and thus provides us with a workaround for crappy IE.

```
if (!this.files) alert('message');
```

working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/whiteb0x/nHBDp/