# multer nodejs modules onFileUploadStart file.size returns 0

Tags: node.js, file-upload, asyncfileupload, multer

I am creating an app that receives file from several clients in node.js. For that i use express multer node modules.

In the following code I deal with the file upload:

```
app.use(multer({ dest: './uploads/',
    rename: function (fieldname, filename){
        return filename;
    },
    onFileUploadStart: function(file){
        console.log("file size: " + file.size);
        console.log(file.originalname + ' is starting...');
    },
    onFileUploadComplete: function(file){
        console.log(file.fieldname + ' uploaded to ' + file.path);
        done = true;
    },
    onFileUploadData: function(file, data){
        //console.log("data being received " + data);
    }
}));
```

But when I enter inside the `onFileUploadStart` the `file.size` is 0.

A multer file object is a JSON object with the following properties so I know that the size property exists.

```
fieldname - Field name specified in the form
originalname - Name of the file on the user's computer
name - Renamed file name
encoding - Encoding type of the file
mimetype - Mime type of the file
path - Location of the uploaded file
extension - Extension of the file
size - Size of the file in bytes
truncated - If the file was truncated due to size limitation
buffer - Raw data (is null unless the inMemory option is true)
```

Why is the size being returned as 0?

**EDIT:**
although the file size returns 0 other properties of the file like file.originalname are working and returning the proper names.

**EDIT2:**
when i print the file inside the onFileUploadStart function i get the following properties and associated values:

```
{
    filename: 'userFile',
    originalname: 'name.png',
    name: 'name.png',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'image/png',
    path: 'uploads\\name.png',
    extension: 'png',
    size: 0,
    truncated: null,
    buffer: null
}
```

Why is the multer node module sending everything correctly but the file size?

**EDIT3:**

request.body prints the following:

```
{ submit: 'upload file' }
```

which is weird. 
i am printing the request body inside the following code:

```
app.post('/upload/', function(request, response){
    console.log(request.body);
    if (done == true){
        response.end('file uploaded');
    }
});
```

index.html file where the client can upload a file:

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form id= "upload" enctype= "multipart/form-data" action="/upload/" method="post">
            <input type="file" name="userFile" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="upload file" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show your request body?

Comment: @BenDiamant you can now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only get total the file size after the upload has completed, since the file is streamed.

If you look at the [source](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/blob/master/index.js#L86-L107) you can see the initial size is set to 0, then is increased along with the [data](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/blob/master/index.js#L120) event.

Comment: So maybe if i want to provide the user feedback on how much was uploaded i should use another module? can u provide some modules that would help me doing that?

Comment: `onFileUploadStart` will always return 0. `onFileUploadData` will contain the total uploaded so far.

Comment: I get it. but then i cant do what i want that is to say to the user how long it takes

Comment: You could always calculate the file size using the HTML5 File API, then send this data along with the file. [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112575/client-checking-file-size-using-html5).