# Uploading users data using CSV file with flow JS

Tags: angularjs, ng-file-upload, flow-js

I want to provide upload functionality to my angular JS application , I want to restrict user to upload only CSV/XSL files only,and the File size must be restricted to 100KB ,the users data from the file should be stored in the local storage of browser using Flow JS, I am new to Flow JS ,can anyone give me hint or code-snippet to implement this.I don't wanna use any backend only local storage to store my data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To restrict selectable files to CSV and XLS or XSLX, use *FlowJS* `assignBrowse` method :

```
.assignBrowse(domNodes, isDirectory, singleFile, attributes)
```

This way

```
flow.assignBrowse(element, false, false, {"accept": ".csv,.xls,.xlsx"});
```

Read official docs for more : https://github.com/flowjs/flow.js/#methods

Unfortunately, this is no limit for filesize.

But you'll find some useful information on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112575/client-checking-file-size-using-html5) which could help :