# How to control the size of the image a user can upload

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, django-models

I have a Django app where users can upload images to an S3 bucket, and I tested it with a few users and found out that many uploaded very large photos (up to 55 MB) and when I render the main page, all the images must be displayed. Each time someone browses it, it drains my bandwidth.

Is there a way to limit the size of the image people upload? Perhaps to 10 MB each?

Comment: yes you can use validator.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this - perhaps in a `validators.py`:

```py
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


def validate_file_size(value):
    filesize = value.size
    
    if filesize > 10485760:  # 10 MiB in bytes
        raise ValidationError("The maximum file size that can be uploaded is 10 MiB")
    else:
        return value
```

and then in your `models.py`:

```py
from .validators import validate_file_size

file = models.FileField(..., validators=[validate_file_size])
```

However, this is server side, not client side. Therefore, each submission of the file transmits the file over the wire to you, resulting in bandwidth charges. If someone was to upload a 1 GiB file, then the upload would consume 1 GiB of bandwith, even if it is rejected by the server.

Client-side validation would require some JS like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112575/client-checking-file-size-using-html5), but you would also need server-side validation.

Comment: Thank you very much, is their a way to make a kind of:      if filesize > 10mb: resize the image to 10mb ?? the problem is not really that the user upload big photos it s that i renders those every time i render the gallery because i didn't plan for this kind of situation and i didn't add a "create thumbnail" function and i have no idea how to add it now ... sorry i only started programming a few months ago and my knowledge is still very basic

Comment: You could use Pillow [like this](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#create-thumbnails), but you have to be careful because if someone uploads a non-image, it could (_could!_) expose you to arbitrary code execution vulnerabilities.

Comment: Thank you very much !