# Error 503: service unavailable on image displaying in HTML

Tags: html, image, http-status-code-503

I've recently uploaded a website, and I'm having issues with images displaying: 
Some of my images won't load and return a 503: service unavailable error.

In fact, I think the only images that load are the ones saved in cache memory, because if I refresh the page 3-4 times all the images get loaded.

I tried to contact my host, but they only responded I had low speed problems (Google tools tell me I should absolutely resize my images) and I'm not sure 4 images, even if they are big, cause too much trouble to get uploaded, am I wrong?

For further details, here is for example a page that bugs:

http://cookeup.fr/articles/sucr%C3%A9/Cookies+extra+moelleux+%28option+brownies%29

Comment: Your images are behind some sort of login- I get a [page like this](https://c9.io/signin.html?redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fc9.io%2Fapi%2Fnc%2Fauth%3Fresponse_type%3Dtoken%26client_id%3Duser.content%26state%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fcookeup-arthurdeschamps23.c9users.io%252FimagesArticles%252FJennifer%252Fingr%2525C3%2525A9dientssss.jpg&login_hint=&style=) on trying to load them up.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the problem. I uploaded my images when I was working on the cloud and saved their urls in my database, which I copied on the production database, so every link lead to my cloud9 space, which is password protected. How did I not see that.. Thank you anyway !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as though anything that has *c9users.io* in the url such as http://cookeup-arthurdeschamps23.c9users.io/imagesArticles/Jennifer/2nd%20step.jpg is getting redirected for login details. Which can be replicated by simply attempting to visit that URL.

For the images that work, such as the title: http://cookeup.fr/Frontend/images/title.jpg you can see that these are not being redirected. I assume that there will be a redirect in the .htaccess for the website.

To get around this the easy way, I would try and put the images which aren't working in the same directory as the title.

As for the image size issue, I always compress everything with https://tinypng.com/ .

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Almost every images had been uploaded when I was working on the cloud on my website (cloud9), so of course every urls were not accurate and were trying to retrieve files from my cloud9, which is password protected. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Definitely try resizing your images. Even if it doesn't fix your issue, it will assist in the loading time of your website. Additionally, try re-uploading your images and check how they are linked on your site.

Comment: I might do that but since they can take any size (because they are uploaded by users and sized afterwards), I'm gonna have to think for a while about how to do this, and for now I really need these images to be displayed. Do you have any other ideas ?

Comment: @ArthurDeschamps You can limit upload size: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327965/html-upload-max-file-size-does-not-appear-to-work

Comment: It is pretty important that you resize your images, because large images increase the loading time, which I could see when loading your site, there was a large delay on the loading time of the image at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, a 503 error occurs because the server is

- *too busy* or
- *there's maintenance being performed* on it.

You might want to ***compress or resize*** your images before uploading it to server , as they might be large enough to keep the server busy and show the error.

Moreover , check for the Relative URL of the images  ,(*not necessary*) but helps sometimes.