# Stopping the upload process if the upload limit I chose is exceeded

Tags: upload, limit

I am working on a web site project PHP/APACHE without any js until now.

I found out various ways to set the upload limit of an image to the server.

They work, but when I upload a very large one, the delay before the message "your file is too big" is from far too long. This means if a user does'nt understand what max 2.4MB is he will be likely to wait more than a minute or 2 before seeing the message.

My question is :

Do you know any mean to have the uopload automatically cancelled if the image he tries to transfer exceeds the limit ?

Thank a lot

SunnyOne.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, there are 2 ways to do this: With Flash/Java, or with fancy HTML5 JavaScript that only works on some browsers (and the most recent version of those, as well.

Check these other SO questions for pointers:
[Client Checking file size using HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112575/client-checking-file-size-using-html5) and [Detecting file upload size on the client side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934788/detecting-file-upload-size-on-the-client-side).

Also, check out these tools: [YUI2 Uploader](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/uploader/), [FancyUpload](http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/), [SWFUpload](http://swfupload.org/)