# How to get image size of a form field (formData) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, file-upload, multipartform-data, form-data

Any idea how to get size in bytes of an image within a validating javascript function so that user will be prompted to pick a valid image size. I have seen other answers which handle this out of the form logic, but I want to know if I can get the size within the validation javascript function. Thanks

Here is my Form related code:

```html
<form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validateForm(this)">
    <script>
        function validateForm(form) {
            var image_name = form.image.value;
            if (image_name == null || image_name == "") {
                alert('Select an image');
                return false;
            } else return true;
        }
    </script>
    <label> Image (300 KB max.) <input type="file" name="image" /> </label>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: BTW, "size of an image" is ambiguous - I assume from the code you mean the number of bytes not the height/width pixels?

Comment: Correct, I want to know number of bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     $first_name=$_POST['fname'];
    echo 'Entered First Name = '.$first_name;
 }
 ?>
 <html>

 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
     <label for="fname"> First Name: </label> <input  type="text" name="fname"  /> <br /><br />
     <label for="file"> Select File: </label> <input  type="file" id="file" />
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
 </form>

 <script>
 document.forms[0].addEventListener('submit', function( evt ) {
     var file = document.getElementById('file').files[0];

     if(file && file.size < 18000) { 
         //Submit form
        alert('Size is valid');
     } else {
        alert('pic too big');
        evt.preventDefault();
     }
 }, false);
 </script>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML5 File API supports file size check.
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

```
    <input type="file" id="image" />

    var size = document.getElementById("image").files[0].size;

or  
     var size = document.getElementsByName("image")[0].files[0].size; // edit added
```

But its a better idea to put a server side validation for file size too.

**Note** : this won't work on older browsers

Also check this question :
[Detecting file upload size on the client side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934788/detecting-file-upload-size-on-the-client-side) and
 [Stopping the upload process if the upload limit I chose is exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851722/stopping-the-upload-process-if-the-upload-limit-i-chose-is-exceeded?lq=1)

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wKvf8/

Comment: When I put the above line "var size = document.getElementById("image").files[0].size;", The validation function stop working. Not sure if there is some syntax error. I am using IE 9.

Comment: As soon as I use id="image" instead of name="image" other places in the program where I refer to image get error: if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],'images/'.$_FILES['image']['name']))
       {  
           print '<p> The file has been successfully uploaded </p>';
           $fileup="true";
       }

Comment: @user2026794 Use both name and id for the element then.

Comment: @user2026794 you can also use `document.getElementsByName("image")[0].files[0].size` .. i have made an edit to the answer

Comment: After using document.getElementsByName("image")[0].files[0].size; I am not getting the error but somehow control exits from the Javascript validation function without executing anything. When I comment out this line, the function works fine. I think we are very close but there may be some error in the statement or something.

Comment: same problem if I user "var file = document.getElementByID('image').files[0];" script just exits from this line and doesn't execute lines after that.

Comment: I have added a fiddle example  http://jsfiddle.net/wKvf8/ ..seems to work.. check the javascript console in your browser for any errors.. Press F12 to bring the debug bar

Comment: Thank you very much for doing this, but somehow your code still does not display any results upon running in jsfiddle. Maybe something to do with my browser. Anyway, I have found a way which is working and I am posting it so that it will help someone.

Comment: nice.. great to see you found and shared the answer

Comment: Just tried your code (jsfiddle) in Fire fox and it worked. Not sure why it won't in IE9. In IE f12 is showing following error: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property '0': object is null or undefined 
_display, line 22 character 5

Comment: Seems IE9 doesnt support File API http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349144/will-ie9-support-the-html5-file-api