# MVC FileUpload file size client side validation

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, validation

How can I validate file size from client side. It can be controlled via controller like,

`if (file.ContentLength > 1048600)
  {
  }`

also on client side I can control name and extension of file. But how control size?

`<input type="file"  name="file" id="file" />`

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont think there is currently a cross browser way to do what you want, check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934788/detecting-file-upload-size-on-the-client-side)

This can work only in webkit based browsers for example

```
var size = document.getElementById('file').files[0].size;
```