# How can I validate the files size of uploaded files before upload?

Tags: validation, filesize

So I need a way of validating the sum total of multiple files being uploaded. I know this needs to be done on the client's side but I am not sure how to implement it. Here is the form I amusing:

```
 <form action="upload.php" method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <input type="file" name="image[]"  multiple="multiple">
        <input type="submit" value="upload">
 </form>
```

Comment: Check out a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934788/detecting-file-upload-size-on-the-client-side

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in HTML5, something like:

```
var file = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[0];
// now you can get the size via: 
var fileSize = file.size;
```